# awk: counting fields in a variable

Tags: awk

Given a string like `{running_db_nodes,[ejabberd@host002,ejabberd@host001]},` , how could the number of comma-delimited strings in square brackets be counted?

The useful substring can be extracted with gensub:
`awk '/running_db_nodes/ {print gensub(/ {running_db_nodes,\[(.*)\]},/, "\\1", 1)}'` .

A naive approach with NF gets fields from the original input string:
`awk -F, '/running_db_nodes/ {nodes=gensub(/ {running_db_nodes,\[(.*)\]},/, "\\1", 1); print NF}'`

How could the number of fields in a variable like `nodes` in the last example be extracted?

Comment: This looks like JSON. Isn't it?

Comment: Or if not, where this output comes from?

Comment: Is this a misprocessed JSON? Perhaps you can go back to source and extract/manipulate it properly with `jq`.

Comment: It's from `ejabberdctl mnesia all`. It resembles JSON, but does not seem to be valid JSON. The input string is extracted from full output, but is unchanged otherwise.

Comment: You can combine your pattern and gensub call to a single `match()` call with an array argument if you use GNU Awk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set your FS to characters `[` and `]`, then split your `$2` to an array and capture the count of elements returned from `split()`:

```
 echo "{running_db_nodes,[ejabberd@host002,ejabberd@host001]}," |
     awk -F"[][]" '{print split($2,a,",")}'
 2
```

Comment: Thank you, that's neat, and it also indirectly answers my question on counting the fields in a variable - `split(nodes,a,",")}`.

Comment: Brilliant use of `split`.

Comment: There are several great answers, but I'll accept this one, as it also included the solution for "count fields in a variable".

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples only and with shown attempts please try following `awk` code.

```bash
echo "{running_db_nodes,[ejabberd@host002,ejabberd@host001]}," | 
awk '
{
  gsub(/.*\[|\].*$/,"")
  print gsub(/,/,"&")+1
}
'
```

***Explanation:*** Simple explanation would be:

- `gsub(/.*\[|\].*$/,"")`: Globally substituting everything from starting to till `[` AND substituting from `[` to till end of value with NULL in current line.
- `print gsub(/,/,"&")+1`: Globally substituting `,` with itself(just to count it) and adding `1` to it and printing it as pre requirement.

Comment: Counting commas is neat, although it feels a bit hackish :)

Answer (score 1):

> A naive approach with NF gets fields from the original input string

`gensub` does not change string it is working on, you might use `sub` (or `gsub`) which will alter string it is working at which will alter relevant built-in variables values that is

```
echo "{running_db_nodes,[ejabberd@host002,ejabberd@host001]}" | awk 'BEGIN{FS=","}{sub(/^.*\[/,"");sub(/].*$/,"");print NF}'
```

gives output

```
2
```

Explanation: use `sub` to delete everything before `[` and `[`, then `]` and everything behind it, `print` number of fields.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)*

Comment: Thanks, great to see a way to use NF in the end. I fixated on `gensub` too early.